# Unexpected One-Factor in EFA

Tags: factor-analysis

I have a data set of 4,000 participants. Each has rated 25 sentences on a scale of 1-100 (lowest amount of aggression present to highest amount of aggression present in each scenario portrayed in the sentences).

I was not sure how many factors I would find, however I had predicted there would perhaps be 3 or 4 factors, grouping those sentences that were rated as containing the most aggression together, moderate items together, and low items together.

My SPSS EFA is giving me only one factor. I cannot find any problems with my data, and wondered if anyone else has encountered this, and if it could in fact be possible to only have one factor, when the average percentages for each of the items range from 54% to 87% (or if there must be something wrong)?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong. The number of factors to extract is a semi-arbitrary decision, so what do you mean when you say that you are only getting one factor?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the scree plot there is only one point above the drop/break, and only one factor has an eigenvalue greater than one (although I am aware eigenvalues are one of the least accurate methods).

Comment: Hmmm... this suggests that some people just rate high, and some people just rate low. You could remove that effect by mean centering or standardizing within person (calculate the mean for each person, and subtract that from each of their scores). That's kind of like extracting the first factor (with all loadings equal to 1) and then discarding it. Or you could just extract more factors. In a CFA framework you might do a bifactor model.

Comment: I think that may be the case (rating high); despite informing participants that all items are representative of some level of aggression (as determined in an earlier study), I think a lot of people couldn't bring themselves to rate items below 50 on the 1-100 scale for fear of suggesting it wasn't aggressive. Oh the joys of social science research.

I will definitely try mean centering or standardizing.

I am not familiar with a bifactor model but I just found an article by Reiss (2011) on Bifactor Models and Rotations. Looking forward to reading through it. Thanks for your help!